# How to export excel from List<string> C#?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, arraylist, export-to-csv

I have the list with content look like that

```
"Food"<|||>"Candy"<|||>"15"
"System"<|||>"IOS, Android"<|||>"2023"
"Fruit"<|||>"Apple,Orange "<|||>"100"
"Wine"<|||>"Whisky"<|||>"250"
```

I try specific character  `<|||>` , which will be define separated to excel format . The excel result will have 3 columns .

[image]

but i don't know it can be do, this looks difficult because excel will only identify on commas, not sure if it can use special characters, and inside the cell content, we also have commas.

```
var lines = new List<string>();
lines.AddRange("Food"<|||>"Candy"<|||>"15","System"<|||>"IOS, Android"<|||>"2023","Fruit"<|||>"Apple,Orange "<|||>"100","Wine"<|||>"Whisky"<|||>"250");
//export to excel
```

Comment: `inside the cell content, we also have commas` - commas are allowed in CSV, this is a long-solved problem. [Refer to this standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). For C#, look-up any good [CSV export library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: Check this answer will convert any List<T> into a .xlsx (excel) file using openxml https://stackoverflow.com/a/75710956/888472

Comment: For sure with that solution you wont neither use the conversion of the object to the string

Comment: BTW your code even compile.

Comment: Just add the data to the list and then if the last column of your excel is to contain a number then use Int32.TryParse and check if it's an int then break a like instead of adding a comma in your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the last column of your excel file contains an integer then you can use a conditional structure to check if the array member at the current index contains a number using `Int32.TryParse()` then you append that item and a line break to the csv else append the item and a comma like in the code below.

```
var array = new string[]
{
    "Food","Candy","15",
    "System","IOS, Android","2023",
    "Fruit","Apple, Orange","100",
    "Wine","Whisky","250"
};
//create a new list to hold the items
var myList = new List<string>();
//copy the items from the array to the list
myList.AddRange(array);
//create the csv file if it does not exist
if (!File.Exists("items.csv"))
{
    File.Create("items.csv");
}
//open the file with a stream writer for editing
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("items.csv"))
{
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(item, out var res))
        {
            //append the item to the file and a line break
            streamWriter.Write(item+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //replace the comma in the current string with space
            var str = item.Replace(",", " ");
            //append the item and a comma
            streamWriter.Write(str+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Check the excel output of the file `item.csv` below.
[image]